# Sharepoint Custom Field Render pattern: loop through Sub Columns of Multiple Column field

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Custom Sharepoint field that inherits from `SPFieldMultiColumn`. the values of the field appear like this:

> ";#column one value;#column two
>   value;#column three value;#"

I want to display each item in a separate line and remove the

> ;#

I checked this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms411957(office.12).aspx
and found that this can be achieved by overriding the render pattern of the field like this

```
<RenderPattern Name="DisplayPattern" DisplayName="DisplayPattern">
  <Switch>
    <Expr>
      <GetVar Name="FreeForm"/>
    </Expr>
    <Case Value="TRUE">
      <Column/>
    </Case>
    <Default>
      <HTML>
        <![CDATA[ <DIV ALIGN=RIGHT> ]]>
      </HTML>
      <Column/>
      <HTML>
        <![CDATA[ </DIV> ]]>
      </HTML>
    </Default>
  </Switch>
</RenderPattern>
```

bu this requires that the number of SubColumns to be predefined, in my case it can be any number.

so I need a for loop to loop through each subcolumn in my multiple column field?

how can this be done ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mina,

I am running out of gas on helping you, here is the full content of my Xml and related class headers for your reference, good luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FieldTypes>
  <FieldType>
    <Field Name="TypeName">CountryStateCityAddress1Field</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeDisplayName">CountryStateCityAddress1Field</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeShortDescription">CountryStateCityAddress1Field</Field>
    <Field Name="ParentType">MultiColumn</Field>
    <Field Name="UserCreatable">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="FieldTypeClass">c0d4e972-cae4-4320-b13b-83ed0bf8cedc</Field>
    <RenderPattern Name="DisplayPattern">
      <Switch>
        <Expr>
          <Column />
        </Expr>
        <Case Value="" />
        <Default>
          <Column SubColumnNumber="0" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[<br/>]]></HTML>
          <Column SubColumnNumber="1" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[<br/>]]></HTML>
          <Column SubColumnNumber="2" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[<br/>]]></HTML>
        </Default>
      </Switch>
    </RenderPattern>
  </FieldType>
  <FieldType>
    <Field Name="TypeName">EMailFieldTypeField</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeDisplayName">EMailFieldTypeField</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeShortDescription">EMailFieldTypeField</Field>
    <Field Name="ParentType">MultiColumn</Field>
    <Field Name="UserCreatable">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="FieldTypeClass">0e8a370a-0388-4b78-9e5c-ffbb8a481391</Field>
    <RenderPattern Name="DisplayPattern">
      <Switch>
        <Expr>
          <Column />
        </Expr>
        <Case Value="" />
        <Default>
          <Column SubColumnNumber="0" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[<br/>]]></HTML>
          <Column SubColumnNumber="1" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[<br/>]]></HTML>
          <Column SubColumnNumber="2" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[<br/>]]></HTML>
        </Default>
      </Switch>
    </RenderPattern>
  </FieldType>
</FieldTypes>
```

Headers:

```
namespace CustomFieldTypeAddress1
{
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    [Guid("0e8a370a-0388-4b78-9e5c-ffbb8a481391")]
    public class EMailFieldTypeField : SPFieldMultiColumn 
    ...

namespace CustomFieldTypeAddress1
{
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    [Guid("dc20d765-2d36-4396-83aa-f063166d8fcc")]
    public class EMailFieldTypeFieldControl : BaseFieldControl  
    ...
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, your solution works fine if you have the number of subcolumn pre-defined as you did (you specefied 3 sub columns). In my case the number of subcolumns is dynamic, so my question was how to make a CAML query in the render pattern of the field that loops through a dynamic number of sub columns Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom field control.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862248.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417414%28office.12%29.aspx) for starting info on how to do this.

This gives you great flexibility in displaying the field, however it does involve more code.

Comment: Thanks, I already created the custom field, but I need a CAML loop to loop each sub column in the multiple column field to adjust it's appearence

Comment: I was thinking of a custom field .asx control where you have full control over the rendering experience.

Comment: Pretty much xslt has to be the way to go when you have an xml datasource for sue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem which was caused by ParentType in the Xml file

Before fixing:

```
<Field Name="ParentType">Text</Field>"
```

After fixing it:

```
<Field Name="ParentType">MultiColumn</Field>"
```

Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd727508.aspx.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your response. but I already tried this before but did not solve anything

Answer (score 0):

whan `SPFieldMultiColumn` object use the method `override BaseFieldControl FieldRenderingControl` it load the object which inherit from the `BaseFieldControl`,

So, the object which inherit the `BaseFieldControl` has a method that call

```
protected override void RenderFieldForDisplay(HtmlTextWriter output){}
```

in this method you can render you controls that fits you.

You can use the example below

```
namespace SharePointTestApplication
{
    public class UserChoiceColumn:SPFieldMultiColumn
    {
        public UserChoiceColumn(SPFieldCollection fields, string fname)
            : base(fields, fname) { }

        public UserChoiceColumn(SPFieldCollection fields, string tname, string dname)
            : base(fields, tname, dname) { }

        public override BaseFieldControl FieldRenderingControl
        {
            get
            {
                BaseFieldControl ctr = new UserChoiceColumnControlType();
                ctr.FieldName = this.InternalName;
                return ctr;
            }
        }

        public override string GetFieldValueAsHtml(object value)
        {

            SPFieldMultiColumnValue mcv = new SPFieldMultiColumnValue(value.ToString());

            return string.Format("{0} , {1}",mcv[0],mcv[1]);
        }


    }

    public class UserChoiceColumnControlType : BaseFieldControl
    {
        #region Protected Members 

        protected TextBox TextBox1;
        protected TextBox TextBox2;

        #endregion

        protected override string DefaultTemplateName
        {
            get
            {
                return "UserChoiceColumnTemplate";
            }
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();
            TextBox1 = (TextBox)this.TemplateContainer.FindControl("TextBox1");
            TextBox2 = (TextBox)this.TemplateContainer.FindControl("TextBox2");
        }

        public override object Value
        {
            get
            {
                this.EnsureChildControls();
                SPFieldMultiColumnValue mcv = new SPFieldMultiColumnValue(2);
                mcv[0] = TextBox1.Text;
                mcv[1] = TextBox2.Text;
                return mcv;
            }
            set
            {
                this.EnsureChildControls();
                SPFieldMultiColumnValue mcv = (SPFieldMultiColumnValue)this.ItemFieldValue;
                TextBox1.Text = mcv[0];
                TextBox2.Text = mcv[1];
            }
        }

        **protected override void RenderFieldForDisplay(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            output.Write("hello world");
           // base.RenderFieldForDisplay(output);
        }**

    }
}
```